# Mutating a global variable from within a function

Tags: python, global-variables

If I start a script with something like:

```
someVar = "none"

def someFunction():
    if whatever is whatever:
        someVar = "somethingElse"
    return someVar
```

Then, in a different function I check someVar, will someVar be "none" or "somethingElse"?

I hoped "somethingElse", but instead, having written a function that sets someVar to something else, I'm finding that someVar remains "none".

Is that expected? If you manipulate a global variable fromw ithin a function does the global variable change going forwards?

Comment: I would argue that is is better style to pass that variable in as an argument to the function, or create a class that contains that variable and the function.  Using globals in python is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `global` keyword which means you'll be modifying the global variable `someVar`:

```
someVar = "none"

def someFunction():
    global someVar
    if whatever is whatever:
        someVar = "somethingElse"
    return someVar
```

Comment: thank you! Accepting shortly. so saying "global someVar" anywhere in the function just means that any further reference to that variable within the function is at the global level

Comment: Yes, that's what global does.